# How to synchronize threads/CPUs without mutexes if sequence of access is known to be safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization, memory-barriers

Consider the following:

```
// these services are running on different threads that are started a long time ago
std::vector<io_service&> io_services;

struct A {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> u;
} a;

io_services[0].post([&io_services, &a] {
      std::unique_ptr<Object> o{new Object};

      a.u = std::move(o);

      io_services[1].post([&a] {
            // as far as I know changes to `u` isn't guaranteed to be seen in this thread 
            a.u->...;
          });
    });
```

The actual code passes a struct to a bunch of different `boost::asio::io_service` objects and each field of struct is filled by a different service object **(the struct is never accessed from different io_service objects/threads at the same time, it is passed between the services by reference until the process is done)**.

As far as I know I always need some kind of explicit synchronization/memory flushing when I pass anything between threads even if there is no read/write race (as in simultaneous access). What is the way of correctly doing it in this case?

Note that **Object** does not belong to me and it is not trivially copy-able or movable. I could use a `std::atomic<Object*>` (if I am not wrong) but I would rather use the smart pointer. Is there a way to do that?

Edit:
It seems like [std::atomic_thread_fence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) is the tool for the job but I cannot really wrap the 'memory model' concepts to safely code.
My understanding is that the following lines are needed for this code to work correctly. Is it really the case?

```
// these services are running on different threads that are started a long time ago
std::vector<io_service&> io_services;

struct A {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> u;
} a;

io_services[0].post([&io_services, &a] {
      std::unique_ptr<Object> o{new Object};

      a.u = std::move(o);

      std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

      io_services[1].post([&a] {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

            a.u->...;
          });
    });
```

Comment: If there is no simultaneous r/w (and you're 100% sure about this), then I fail to see why there's any need for sync'ing.

Comment: @lorro `std::atomic` and C++11 memory model do define different methods of synchronizations. I feel like those should apply any data interchange between threads, whether thread is exited or not. Memory model suggests that there is normally no guarantee that writes by one thread can be seen by the other by default, even if order is safe.

Comment: We've got a terminology issue here. The very meaning of 'order' is a bijective mapping between the specific times of two threads until one of them exits. So if you write to a memory address, as soon as your thread reaches the next sequence point (e.g., `;`), it's guaranteed that the other thread can read that loc, but reaching that sequence point might take *arbitrary long* viewed from a different thread. Think about it: if it didn't hold, we wouldn't have nice lock-free queues.

Comment: @lorro That might be the case but I am not really familiar with these types of inter-thread communications (without mutexes). Actual piece of code randomly crashes on GCC6.1.1 because the move operator somehow calls the destructor and access by the consecutive thread does an invalid access (according to valgrind). I thought it was due to corruption/race because of an improper synchronization. But if you are sure there is no need, then post it as an answer please.

Comment: It's already posted by Smeeheey I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(I'd like to remark that you appear to have changed your question in some significant way since @Smeeheey answered it; essentially, he answered your originally-worded question but cannot get credit for it since you asked two different questions. This is poor form – in the future, please just post a new question so the original answerer can get credit as due.)</sup>

If multiple threads read/write a variable, even if *you* know said variable is accessed in a defined sequence, you *must* still inform the compiler of that. The correct way to do this necessarily involves synchronization, atomics, or something documented to perform one of the prior itself (such as `std::thread::join`). Presuming the synchronization route is both obvious in implementation and undesirable..:

Addressing this with atomics *may* simply consist of `std::atomic_thread_fence`; however, an acquire fence in C++ cannot *synchronize-with* a release fence alone – an actual atomic object must be modified. Consequently, if you want to use fences alone you'll need to specify `std::memory_order_seq_cst`; that done, your code will work as shown otherwise.

If you want to stick with release/acquire semantics, fortunately even the simplest atomic will do – [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag):

```
std::vector<io_service&> io_services;

struct A {
  std::unique_ptr<Object> u;
} a;
std::atomic_flag a_initialized = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

io_services[0].post([&io_services, &a, &a_initialized] {
    std::unique_ptr<Object> o{new Object};

    a_initialized.clear(std::memory_order_release); // initiates release sequence (RS)
    a.u = std::move(o);
    a_initialized.test_and_set(std::memory_order_relaxed); // continues RS

    io_services[1].post([&a, &a_initialized] {
        while (!a_initialized.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) ; // completes RS

        a.u->...;
    });
});
```

For information on release sequences, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release_sequence).

Comment: I am sorry about the question modification. Apparently first question was not what I actually intended to ask due to mechanisms I was not aware of. I thought he would edit his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Synchronisation is only needed when there would be a data race without it. A data race is defined as unsequenced access by different threads.

You have no such unsequenced access. The `t.join()` guarantees that all statements that follow are sequenced strictly after all statements that run as part of `t`. So no synchronisation is required.

**ELABORATION:** (To explain why `thread::join` has the above claimed properties) First, description of `thread::join` from standard [thread.thread.member]:

> void join();
>
> 3. Requires: joinable() is true.
> 4. Effects: Blocks until
>      the thread represented by *this has completed.
> 5. Synchronization: The
>      completion of the thread represented by *this **synchronizes with (1.10)
>      the corresponding successful join() return**.

a). The above shows that `join()` provides synchronisation (specifically: the completion of the thread represented by *this synchronises with the outer thread calling `join()`). Next [intro.multithread]:

> 13. An evaluation A *inter-thread happens before* an evaluation B if
>
> (13.1) — A synchronizes with B, or ...

Which shows that, because of a), we have that the completion of `t` *inter-thread happens before* the return of the `join()` call.

Finally, [intro.multithread]:

> 23. Two actions are potentially concurrent if
>
> (23.1) — they are performed
>   by different threads, or
>
> (23.2) — they are unsequenced, and at least
>   one is performed by a signal handler.
>
> The execution of a program
>   contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent
>   conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither
>   *happens before* the other ...

Above the required conditions for a data race are described. The situation with `t.join()` does not meet these conditions because, as shown, the completion of `t` does in fact *happen-before* the return of `join()`.

So there is no data race, and all data accesses are guaranteed well-defined behaviour.

Comment: The data is actually passed between different IO services without joining of any thread though. I was not aware joining ensures a synchronization.

Comment: Can you make this a bit clearer by changing your example code so I know exactly what you mean? Currently it doesn't show any such thing

Comment: Would you say `t.join()` is a form of synchronisation, in the end?

Comment: Yes it is, because the thread calling `join()` cannot proceed before the subject of `join()` executes all its statements and exits.

Comment: @Smeeheey It does guarantee execution of the statements but is it guaranteed that the statements are flushed out of CPU/core cache so that other thread running on another CPU/core can see the change? `std::atomic` and C++11 memory model does define different methods of synchronizations. I feel like those should apply any data interchange between threads, whether thread is exited or not. **I have also edited the example.**

Comment: See update above. The standard guarantees that there is no data race between accesses in one thread and another if they are separated by a `thread::join` call.

Comment: That BTW includes taking care of things like CPU cache synchronisation